# Probability of a wiener process greater than a time varing constant

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $Xt$ be a Wiener process, and $f$ is a continuous funtion with $f(0)<0$. Is there any way to calculate $Prob(Xt-f(t)>0, \forall t \in (0,T))$?